# Nodejs TFS Build Definition

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild

Can anyone let me know how the build definition for a node.js application should look like? Also how to mention the mocha tests in the Automated tests?

First time when I tried to queue a build, I got an error saying:

> Microsoft.NodejsTools.targets not found.

So I went and copied the `NodejsTools` folder with the .target and dll file in my build server. And I didn't see the error.

Now I get the below error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (132): Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\OstNodeJs.exe" because it was not found.

Comment: The exact same thing is happening to be, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: How do you build it from the cmdline?

Answer (score 0):

You need the node.js framework and the Visual Studio node.js Tools on you build server, too. You just copied the necessarily files and this may result in other problems.

For the executable copy problem you can try to add `<Disable_CopyWebApplication>True</Disable_CopyWebApplication>` in the project file. See here: [Build on TFS wants to copy a executable from Node.js test project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063267/build-on-tfs-wants-to-copy-a-executable-from-node-js-test-project)